# How to reduce dimension of the sampling procedure?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, pca, dimensionality-reduction, gaussian-process

I am stuck with this problem for a long time, hopefully I can get help here!

Basically, I want to sample from a posterior distribution that looks like,
\begin{align*}
X &\sim N(\mu(\theta),\Sigma(\theta))\\
\theta &\sim p(\theta)
\end{align*}
where $X = (x_1,...,x_d)$ for $d$ large saying at least thousands, and the dimension of the hyperparameter $\theta$ is not large, saying $p = 3 \sim 5$ or so.

Therefore like the Gibbs sampling, at each time $i = 1,...,n$, I can do

1. sample $\theta^{(i)}$ from $p(\theta)$
2. sample $X^{(i)}$ from $N(\mu(\theta^{(i)}),\Sigma(\theta^{(i)}))$

In such sampling procedure, the dimension of random numbers are $d+p$ which is large due to large d, since in the second step (2), it is usually done by sampling $z^{(i)} \sim N(0,I)$ and $x^{(i)} = L\,z^{(i)}$, $LL = \Sigma$.

What I wanna is to reduce the dimension of the random samples of X to a relatively small number saying at most 10 or so while the uncertainty or main distributional characteristics can be remained.

One simple way I can come up with is a 1 order approximation that

1. sample $\theta^{(i)}\sim p(\theta)$
2. sample $\xi \sim N(0,1)$
3. $X^{(i)} = \mu(\theta^{(i)}) + \xi\cdot\text{diag}(\Sigma(\theta^{(i)}))$

so that the dimension of random numbers are reduced to only $p+1$ ($\theta$ and one scalar $\xi$).. But I doubt that: there is too much information lost in this simple procedure as (1) only marginal variance is used (2) the random number of each $x_j$, $j = 1,...,d$ are the same as $\xi$.

There is also another way as truncated K-L or PCA, but in my case, the proportion of variance by truncating a small number saying 10 or even 20 is small around 30% or even less...

Could it be possible anyone has any idea about this or similar problem has been investigated somewhere?

Many thanks!

Comment: In which sense is your problem related to a posterior distribution if you sample both $\theta$ and the $X_i$'s?

Comment: @Xi'an sorry for the confusing, p(\theta) and N(\mu,\Sigma) are both posterior distribution after doing some Bayesian inference on the model.

Comment: If you run Gibbs sampling, you should simulate $\theta$ from $p(\theta)\times\varphi(X;\mu(\theta),\Sigma(\theta))$ and $X$ from $\varphi(X;\mu(\theta),\Sigma(\theta))$.

Comment: I am afraid that, if you need to simulate $X$ as well as $\theta$ you cannot reduce the dimension of the simulated vector.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks! I understand that for the fully correct sampling, there should be no way to reduce the dimension of random numbers.. I just wonder if there is a way to do a "partly reasonable" sampling (with losses in the randomness but ideally not much, keeping the main features) with a small number of parameters/random numbers.. The resulting samples may not and will not cover the whole space, but cover most and are distributed in the similar way they should be.. I am not sure whether I am expressing my question clearly... Thanks!

Comment: If you generate a single rv, the randomness you induce is also one-dimensional, so there is no way you can cover the whole space, the outcome is on the opposite on a set of measure zero. I actually still fail to understand why you want to reduce the dimension of the simulated vector. You could also do Gibbs sampling on blocks of $X$.

Comment: @Xi'an ok, thanks! Basically if we want to do sensitivy analysis with metamodel, the dimension of inputs cannot be very large but the random samples X are my inputs to another computer model so that I want to reduce the dimension - not for easy sampling.